# 'LaunchIsDefaultLaunchKey' key in the Notification parameter in applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification)

Tags: macos, nsapplication

The notification parameter in DidFinishLaunching contains a key LaunchIsDefaultLaunchKey which according to Apple documentation is:

> The value for this key is an NSNumber containing a Boolean value. The
> value is false if the app was launched to open or print a file, to
> perform a Service action, if the app had saved state that will be
> restored, or if the app launch was in some other sense not a default
> launch. Otherwise its value will be true.

I m not able to understand the exact usecase for this parameter, like where can we make use of this parameter.

Can I use this key to identify If my application was launched using a universal link?